# How can I modify my AWS Step Functions code to trigger several of the same state machines with different input parameters?

Tags: aws-cdk, aws-step-functions

I am working with the AWS typescript CDK and currently have code that looks like this:

```
new sfn.StateMachine(this, 'HighLevelStateMachine', {
  stateMachineName: 'HighLevelStateMachine',
  definition: sfn.Chain.start(
    new sfnTasks.StepFunctionStartExecution(this, 'A', {
      stateMachine: <state machine A>,
      integrationPattern: sfn.TaskInput.fromObject({
        'commonInput.$': '$$.Execution.Input.commonInput',
        'inputA': '$$.Execution.Input.inputA',
      })
    })
  ).next(
    new sfnTasks.StepFunctionStartExecution(this, 'B', {
      stateMachine: <state machine B>,
      integrationPattern: sfn.TaskInput.fromObject({
        'commonInput.$': '$$.Execution.Input.commonInput',
        'inputB': '$$.Execution.Input.inputB',
      })
    })
  ).next(
    new sfnTasks.StepFunctionStartExecution(this, 'C', {
      stateMachine: <state machine C>,
      integrationPattern: sfn.TaskInput.fromObject({
        'commonInput.$': '$$.Execution.Input.commonInput',
        'inputC': '$$.Execution.Input.inputC',
      })
    })
  )
});
```

It takes an input JSON

```
{
   'commonInput': '...',
   'inputA': '...A',
   'inputB': '...B',
   'inputC': '...C',
}
```

And first calls state machine A with input `{'commonInput': '...', 'inputA': '...A'}`, then calls state machine B with input `{'commonInput': '...', 'inputB': '...b'}`, then state machine C with input `{'commonInput': '...', 'inputC': '...C'}`.

I want to modify it so that instead of just calling state machine B once, it can be called several times in parallel, so that I give it an input JSON

```
{
   'commonInput': '...',
   'inputA': '...A',
   'inputB': ['...B1', '...B2', '...B3', ...],
   'inputC': '...C',
}
```

And it will execute state machine B several times in parallel, with each element of the list `inputB` being used as the execution input to one state machine execution (and all using the same `commonInput`).
It seems that Map is the Step Functions tool to do this, but if there is a straightforward code change for me to make to accomplish this, I haven't found it yet online (I am pretty new to this). Is this something that can be done simply, and what would the new code look like?

I have tried looking up how Map works in the AWS documentation, but the level at which it is explained is too complicated for me at the moment.